# Android onDestroy and finish

Tags: android, ondestroy

I found some answer about the difference between onDestroy and finish.

> Finish will remove the activity from the stack, but will not free the
>   memory and will not call onDestroy in every time.
>   onDestroy will kill the activity and free the memory.

In my situation:
There are 2 activities. A is main activity and B is a activity with some EditText for sending data to server by using Volley.

A -> B -> A

When i sent the data successfully.It will run the finish() to kill B.
B is destroyed. But i call B again, all the data still there (content of EditText). Which means the memory haven't clear.

Did anyone face on those issue?
There are my code:

```
public void update(final Context context, final Map<String,String> data,final Activity activity){//pass B
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url = "http://xxxxxxxx";
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                activity.finish();



            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //mPostCommentResponse.requestEndedWithError(error);
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = data;
                //data.
                //params.put("user",data.get(''));


                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
    }
```

**UPDATED**

Activity B have viewpager and 3 fragment by using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
When i call finish() of B. Those data under the fragments won't clear. I can saw the old data when i start B activity again.

Comment: how do u call update ?

Comment: I put update() into help class, pass B into update() when i press the button. So i call B.finish() after sent the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call below function:

```
someActivity.finish();  // This will free the memory, see notes below
```

It should be noted that all its resources are **queued for garbage collection**, and all memory that was used by this activity will be freed during **next GC cycle**.

If you really want to revoke the memory as soon as possible, override your activities' onDestroy method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();      // notify gc to be called asap
}
```

Note about **Runtime.getRuntime().gc();**  this asks the VM to make its best effort to recycle all discarded objects--quoted from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_gc.htm.

Comment: This is some great info !!

Comment: This is pretty much wrong. The gc() method is merely a hint for the Garbage Collection. You don't force anything with this.
I would say this is nothing but a code smell you should avoid at all cost.

Comment: I think your advise works. However, i found my situation quite special with some fragment.

Comment: @waikwanChiu, please mark it as answer if it is helpful.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. Give me a minute. I need to found the solution to solve my case.